# Apache FOP - Complex Table

Tags: pdf, apache-fop

I have a complex table (multiple header rows and details rows that point to a specific header row) that I need to render in a PDF and have it be ADA compliant.  In Adobe I would make it compliant by opening the table editor.  For each header cell I would go into table cell properties and give it a unique ID.  For each detail row cell, I would go to cell properties and set "Associated Header Cells ID's.

Is there any way to access these properties through FOP?

Comment: There is no mention of being able to set ids on headers here .. https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.6/accessibility.html

Comment: I agree, there is nothing in the documentation that tells how this would be done, but much of what we do in FOP isn't in the documentation, so I'm still hoping.

Comment: It would have to be an extension. RenderX does this rx:header-id and rx:header-idref attributes. Check things in the fox: extensions